# what will be the first process in creating Leaf disease detection android application?

Tags: java, android, opencv

We were task to create a Leaf Disease Detection Application to be implemented in Android. I'm just not sure what are the first steps in implementing this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. By now, your problem statement is far too broad, and might be even off-topic at all. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56659098/edit) at any time.

Comment: Pede kang magtanong nang tungkol sa code dito. Buong project na ang hinihingi mo eh.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be probably to get the to Image processing side of the project. 
You could probably use the K- mean clustering algorithm to predict the type of leaf disease. And the processing should happen in 4 main steps :

1. **Image Acquisition** : Obtaining a lot of images of varying formats from some famous public repository
2. **Image Preprocessing** : To get rid of any noise in the image to enhance it's quality.
3. **Image Segmentation** : The images need to be segmented into various sectors using a **ML classifier (suggest Otsu Classifier) and the k-mean clustering algorithm**. This preps the images for the Feature extraction.
4. **Feature Extraction** : To be able to gracefully predict the infected area. (Mainly shape and texture extraction)

And depending on these steps, the disease is detected. You could also propose a solution to overcome the disease after the disease has been detected.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir. What could be the ideal setup or softwares I can make use to start this? Can I use OpenCV android to make this image processing system?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure you can use Android Studio and OpenCV libraries for the same.